# laravel 4 - how to include an editor into Laravel 4

Tags: editor, laravel, laravel-4

I have an application in Laravel 4 to manage newsletter.
It the back end is possible to write the message that will be sent as email to the users in the list.
There is a simple form with two fiels: subject - body
The point is that i can send only plain text.
It is possible to include an editor with some basics functions:  bold - italic - color - size - headings?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That wouldn't be part of the back end but would be done with javascript.  What you are probably looking for is something like CKEditor which basically hijacks `<textarea>` elements on your page and turns them into almost full featured editors.

How it works is it automatically inserts appropriate HTML tags into the text as it's typed depending on how the user wants it to look.  When the form is submitted, instead of plain text, it would be submitted as the generated HTML, and you'd probably just want to drop that into the body of the email.

Check out http://www.ckeditor.com

If you have any specific questions on that, I'd be sure to add the appropriate tags so you have a better chance of getting help on it.